# filestream with IO.FileMode.Open gave me nothing

Tags: vb.net

the whole subroutine

```
Public Sub CopyFile(ByVal NewCopy As String, ByVal FileToCopy As String)
    On Error Resume Next

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FileToCopy) = True Then
        System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)

    Else
        MsgBox("file not found")
    End If

    Dim sr As New IO.FileStream(FileToCopy, IO.FileMode.Open) 'source file
    Dim sw As New IO.FileStream(NewCopy, IO.FileMode.Create) 'target file, defaults overwrite
    Dim len As Long = sr.Length - 1

    ProgressBar1.Visible = True
    For i As Long = 0 To len
        sw.WriteByte(sr.ReadByte)

        If i Mod 1000 = 0 Then
            ProgressBar1.Value = i * 100 / len
            Application.DoEvents()

        End If
    Next

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    ProgressBar1.Visible = False
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 0 Then
        MsgBox("copy done")
        Me.Enabled = True
    End If
    sr.Close()
End Sub
```

When I use this to copy file, sr variable is nothing.  What is wrong?
the file is copyed zero file

i think the error in getting sr variable

Comment: Have you verified that `FileToCopy` exists? In your code you have an IF/Else. The code starting with `Dim SR as new` runs wether or not `File.Exists`

Comment: i post the whole subrotune

Comment: Please remove this line: `On Error Resume Next`. It is masking any error message you would receive. Instead wrapcode in Try/Catch block. You want to validate the data and incase of an unforseen error you can handle it gracefully. To demonstrate the difference in the two using the example of a child who is potty training:  Try/Catch = put on a diaper and tell the child, please let me know if you have to go potty and I will change you if you have an accident. On Error Move next = if you go potty I will  spray a little cologne on your bum and we can worry about it later.

Comment: thanks when i remove the  line: On Error Resume Next. it work

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `on/error resume next` and that will get you much closer to solving the problem. Normally this in itself will not cause the break but based on your comment it appears to have worked.

As an assistance to newbie programmers... **NEVER USE OnError**. You are essentially asking the computer to skip any error and keep going on. This is a very bad thing to do. It might work temporarily but this is a very poor solution.

Debug your code, find out where it breaks and fix the code. If the issue is the user entered some data that causes the break, then put validation in to let them know but never just skip the problem. It will come back to bite you maybe even much later in the code and it will be hard to find out that the code many lines back is really the culprit.